# cloth tent problem

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have a big problem with a tent, the tent almost never remains in place and falls into the floor. I created a simple cylinder to use as a stick and I added the collision, same thing for the floor. How could I solve this?

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=06659551165230967310 File Source

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to *Edit mode* and select top vertices.
2. In *Object Data* tab create new *Vertex Group* and click *Assign*.

[image: 1z]

3. Go to *Physics* tab and check *Pinning* and select *Vertex Group*.

[image: 2z]